# Extra space on top of the first comment in iOS app

Tags: bug, comments, design, ios-app, emoji

The first comment of [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/1099/86) has an extra space on top, presumably by the emoji.

[image]

However it's fine when viewed from the inbox:

[image]

iPhone version:

[image: enter link description here]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)